# Apache Camel and REST web service

Tags: apache, apache-camel

I am working on a project involving [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer) web services. I need to invoke them from Apache Camel and read in its documentation that cxfrs is the required component, but there is no detailed explanation on how to do so. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Rest webservices via camel are fairly straight forward if you are previously familiar with camel.  The documentation for setting up a client side call with one is here: http://camel.apache.org/cxfrs.html  Otherwise if you need a full example I recommend checking out: https://github.com/jeffmaher/jaxrs-cxf-camel-spring-example

Comment: You have mentioned the condition somebody is previously familiar with camel but I am a novice in camel and I am not familar with spring too. I want to do it using Java DSL.

Comment: Camel has a lot of documentation on how to get started.  If you don't want to setup the cxf with spring you can follow this guide: http://camel.apache.org/cxf-example.html